# How disable scroll on body in vue

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js

I'm trying to disable the scroll when my preloader component is displayed. I was using the overflow hidden bootstrap class in the main container of my components but without success, the scroll will remain. Is there a way to remove the scroll on the body of the app only when the preloader is visible?

```
<template>
  <div class="container-fluid main" :class="{ 'overflow-hidden': preloader }">
    <search-bar></search-bar>
    <preloader :preloader="preloader" />
    <user-profile />
    <user-media />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { EventBus } from '@/standalone/event-bus'
import SearchBar from '@/components/SearchBar'
import Preloader from '@/components/Preloader'
import UserProfile from '@/components/UserProfile'
import UserMedia from '@/components/UserMedia'

export default {
  name: 'Index',
  components: {
    SearchBar,
    Preloader,
    UserProfile,
    UserMedia
  },
  data() {
    return {
      preloader: false,
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    //browser.runtime.sendMessage({})
    EventBus.$on('show-preloader', () => {
      this.preloader = true;
    })
    EventBus.$on('hide-preloader', () => {
      this.preloader = false;
    })
  }
}
</script>

<style>
/* @import '~bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css'; */

</style>
```

Comment: Please add vue tag also.

Comment: Please, insert a css files in jsfiddle or similar